# Centos 5 - Configuring a crontab PHP job

Tags: centos, cron, centos5

I'm running a CentOS 5 server, and trying to schedule a job which runs a php file every day at the same time, I've added a new file to the directory

> /etc/cron.d/

called `get_files`

The `get_files` file contains the following:

```
03 6 * * * php /var/www/html/get-info.php
```

However, the above job doesn't seem to get run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is an *excellent* canonical answer.  It probably covers every cron-related question we've ever had here.

Comment: @Ladadadada: It is now, the $original was full of $fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the full path to php, and use the -f switch

```
03 6 * * * /path/to/php -f /var/www/html/get-info.php
```

Answer (score 2):

The cron jobs in `/etc/cron.d/` (and also `/etc/contab`) have **six** parts before the command, not five.  The first five are as you expect, the schedule.  The sixth is the user the command should run as.

Cron files often have explicitly set variables such as `SHELL` and `PATH` which avoids requiring full paths to everything in the rest of the cron file.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
03 6 * * * root php /var/www/html/get-info.php
```

Your original cron job would have been logging an error in `/var/log/cron` saying that it couldn't find the user "php".